# I want tab bar on top so i used VSTabBar but i got implicit conversion error

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbar, enumeration, implicit-conversion

Actually i am using VSTab bar for tab on top. But I got an error.

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type "UITextAlignment" to different enumeration type "NSTextAlignment"
```

If anyone has a better solution for top bar tab.than thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, you can use layout constraints to stick your tab on top..

Comment: `UITextAlignment` is deprecated. Find and replace it with `NSTextAlignment`.

Comment: hey,@Kampai can you please help me.i am beginners in programming and also in iPhone app development.can you please guide me.can you please tell me the flow how i learn?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @qɿiyɘƨʜ: About learning. As much as you experience in iPhone development, you will learn by your self. Stat with simple examples and read about related control class help from Apple documentation.

Comment: thanks @Kampai but it would be great if you give me some stuff or suggest.cause i tired a lot to getting something but i am beginners so i can't get properly.and also i don't know about objective c so that's why i have to faced all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

"UITextAlignment is deprecated. Find and replace it with NSTextAlignment." Try this answer mentioned in comment. It will fix your warning.